# Fancybox not working on product page in prestashop

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I have on-line store on prestashop 1.5.6. 
There is a fancybox for images on product page, but it's not working. When click on image, will open new page with only image.
Firebug doesn't show any errors, and I can't find where is the problem.
5 weeks ago everything was ok.
This is link to product page - http://maxafashion.com/ru/dress/7-ecouteurs-a-isolation-sonore-shure-se210-blanc.html
Can anybody help me with a smart mind?

Comment: `5 weeks ago everything was ok` then you need to check what you have modified in the last 5 weeks only ;) ... I would start with [validating the document](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://maxafashion.com/en/dress/7-ecouteurs-a-isolation-sonore-shure-se210-blanc.html), which will give you an idea what might be wrong

Comment: I found the problem! It was the conflict between lightbox and form validator))